# jquery setTimeout not working in this function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I hit submit, I want this div to popup for a few seconds and then fadeaway. I added the div to the html and have hid it using ('#added').hide(), but it won't appear with the code below:

```
selection = function() {
    ('#added').hide();
    $('#input').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function(event) {
        var add_emp = {
            name: input.name.value,
            wage: input.wage.value,
            role: input.role.value
        };
        Employee(add_emp.name, add_emp.wage, add_emp.role);
        event.preventDefault;
        $('#input').each(function() {
            this.reset();
        });

        $('#added').show();
        setTimeout(function() {

            $('#added').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 5000);

        selection();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$("#added").delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up figuring it out by adding display:none to the css instead of $('#added').hide(); in the js. I don't know why that did it instead!